# List contains method not work on two different classes with the same attributes

Tags: java, equals, contains

I have these two java classes as below:

**RelocationDisabledProduct**

```
public class RelocationDisabledProduct {
    @JsonProperty("productIdentifierType")
    private ProductIdentifierType productIdentifierType;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final Item that = (Item)o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.getId()) &&
            Objects.equals(productIdentifierType, that.getProductIdentifierType());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, productIdentifierType);
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private ProductIdentifierType productIdentifierType;
}
```

equals works fine

```
relocationDisabledProduct.equals(item) // true
```

but contains does not

```
List<RelocationDisabledProduct> relocationDisabledProducts;
...
getRelocationDisabledProducts().contains(item) // false
```

Since **contains** uses the **equals** method, not sure why my above syntax returns false?

Comment: Which implementation of `List<...>`?

Comment: Did you obey every bulleted rule in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for `Object#equals`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to the definition of `AbstractCollection<E> contains(Object o)`.  The Javadoc says

> public boolean contains​(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that Objects.equals(o, e).

Note the order of arguments to `contains()`.  It is using the `equals()` method from `Item`, not the one from `RelocationDisabledProduct`, which you would have probably seen if you stepped into the code in the debugger.

Both `Item` and `RelocationDisabledProduct` need to share a common `equals()` implementation, maybe a default method of a superinterface... you'll have to work out what makes sense in your case.

Comment: In other words, seems you are saying that the implementation of `Item`, having failed to override `Object#equals`, has broken the second rule stated in the `equals` contract defined in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)): ªIt is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.”

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, that's an excellent way of putting it :-)

Comment: My question is why `equals` works but `contains` does not?

Comment: Because when `contains()` does the comparison, it ends up using the `equals()` method from `Item`, which does not override the `Object#equals()` method and does not do what you seem to expect.

Comment: I see, relocationDisabledProduct.equals(item) uses `equals` in `RelocationDisabledProduct` and getRelocationDisabledProducts().contains(item) uses `equals` in `Item`.

Comment: Yes. As @BasilBourque noted, if you're going to write an `equals()` method that accepts a different type of object, it needs to be symmetric -- i.e. return the same result regardless of the order in which the arguments are presented.  That means writing an equivalent `equals()` method for `Item`.  But that way lies madness and eternal curses from those who have to maintain your code. You should refactor things so you don't need to do that.